# How to add pre-selected dates in date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I am using a jQuery datepicker plugin from [KelvinLuck](http://2008.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerMultiple.html). This date picker is a multi-select date picker. In the tutorial it shows how you can add 1 selected date, but I want to add many selected dates like this:

```
.dpSetSelected(
      '18/06/2011', '19/06/2011, '20/06/2011
    )
```

Is this possible? Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a0muv4zr/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `dpSetSelected()` multiple times, e.g: `dpSetSelected('18/06/2011').dpSetSelected('19/06/2011')`

In case of your `for` loop, just replace your JS code with this:

```
var dates = new Array('18/06/2011', '19/06/2011');

$(function() {
  $('.date-pick')
    .datePicker({
      createButton: false,
      displayClose: false,
      closeOnSelect: true,
      selectMultiple: true,
      inline: true,
      startDate: '01/01/2005',
      endDate: '31/12/2011'
    }).bind(
      'click',
      function() {
        $(this).dpDisplay();
        this.blur();
        return false;
      }
    )
    .bind(
      'dateSelected',
      function(e, selectedDate, $td, state) {
        console.log('You ' + (state ? '' : 'un') // wrap
          + 'selected ' + selectedDate);

      }
    );


     for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    $('.date-pick').dpSetSelected(
      dates[i]
    );
  }

});
```

Comment: I'm trying to run a for loop to do so, but it's not working. Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r216sedt/

Comment: @user2896120 I updated my comment, there were 2 problems with your code:
1- Your `for` loop was coming after one of your method calls with a `.` preceding it, just as if it were a function. 
2- the `dates[i]` parameter inside of the method call in your `for` loop had a `;` at the end, parameters can't take semicolons.